# How to write a sum that only includes even terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

Suppose I have a sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)$$ and that for $n$ even $f(n)\neq0$ but for $n$ odd $f(n)=0$ how could I write the sum to indicate that only the even terms need to be summed.

I have seen $$\sum_{\text{n even}}^{\infty}f(n)$$ be used but is there another way where I can write it?

Comment: How about $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(2n)$?

Comment: Yes that will work that you!

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd write $\sum_{n\geq 0\text{ even}}$ instead of $\sum_{n \text{ even}}^\infty$, since you want to specify it is only about the non-negative even numbers, and also, doing a sum from "$n$ even" to "infinity" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f(2n).$$ (If you want only the odd terms, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(2n+1)$ will do the trick.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(2k)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(2k+1)$$